# Defining a fused type using a fused type?

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I'd like to write something like this using [fused types](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/fusedtypes.html) in Cython:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

ctypedef fused T0:
   np.complex128_t
   np.float64_t

ctypedef fused ArrayT0:
   T0[:]
   T0[:,:]

def func(ArrayT0 a):
    cdef T0 ret = a.sum()
    return ret
```

However, it does not work and leads to this compilation error:

```
Compiling bug.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing bug.pyx

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

ctypedef fused T0:
   np.complex128_t
   np.float64_t

ctypedef fused ArrayT0:
^
------------------------------------------------------------

bug.pyx:8:0: Compiler crash in AnalyseDeclarationsTransform

File 'ModuleNode.py', line 124, in analyse_declarations: ModuleNode(bug.pyx:1:0,
    full_module_name = 'bug')
File 'Nodes.py', line 431, in analyse_declarations: StatListNode(bug.pyx:1:0)
File 'Nodes.py', line 1250, in analyse_declarations: FusedTypeNode(bug.pyx:8:0,
    name = 'ArrayT0',
    types = [...]/2)
File 'Nodes.py', line 1273, in analyse: FusedTypeNode(bug.pyx:8:0,
    name = 'ArrayT0',
    types = [...]/2)

Compiler crash traceback from this point on:
  File "/home/pierre/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Nodes.py", line 1273, in analyse
    return PyrexTypes.FusedType(types, name=self.name)
  File "/home/pierre/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/PyrexTypes.py", line 1636, in __init__
    for subtype in t.types:
AttributeError: 'MemoryViewSliceType' object has no attribute 'types'
```

Is there something bad with my Cython code? Shouldn't it work?

Note that this simpler example works fine:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

ctypedef fused T0:
   np.complex128_t
   np.float64_t

def func(T0[:, :] a):
    cdef T0 ret = a.sum()
    return ret
```

Comment: It's usually pretty hard to write useful Cython code when you don't know the number of array dimensions: I don't think current code would work anyway since I don't think a memoryview has a `sum` method, but if you changed it to something like `np.sum(a)` then it'd work but you'd get no benefit from typing it

Comment: The actual code in the function is not really interesting. Anyway, it is for a Python accelerator ([Transonic](https://transonic.readthedocs.io/)), so it can be any codes actually. Also, I used memoryviews, but the same thing applies for `np.ndarray`. It seems that fused types can only be very simple and yes, "
It's usually pretty hard to write useful Cython code when you don't know the number of array dimensions". Except with Pythran maybe...

Comment: I guess my vague suggestions would be: most realistic operations would either be 1) operating element-by-element, in which case you could just flatten (if contiguous) and operate on a 1D array, or 2) "np.einsum" type operations, in which case you could have unaccelerated iteration over the outer dimensions (maybe using `np.nditer, or something you write yourself) with an accelerated iteration over the innermost dimension. But yes, I agree that fused types are pretty limited